# Flutter: Redirect after authentication?

Tags: flutter, authentication, bloc

I am having problems with redirecting users to a certain page after successful sign up. It works sometimes but sometimes, it just won't redirect. But if I exit the app and come back again , then it goes directly into the desired page.I am wondering why this is only working sometimes. I am using Bloc pattern and my code looks like this:

```
_googleSignIn() async {

      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
      try{
      final FirebaseUser user = (await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
         
       Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));
        BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(LoggedIn());

          
      } catch (e) {

      }


  }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more context to your code? For example, where is the `_googleSignIn()` called? From the code above it's difficult to understand where the problem lies but I'd guess is that it might be because you're firing an event in an async action. Using bloc, the proffered way it to alter state within a bloc and listen to the state changes from widget. Here's an [example](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial) that redirects after a Google sign-in

Comment: Thanks @kingJulian, the documentation helped!